# how to send the redux-form data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux-form

I have login component. Here I have used redux-form. As I am new to react, can you help to get the form data from redux-form (how to submit the form data)?

```
<form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
    <div className="padding5">
        <Field name="email" type="email" component={RenderField} label="Email Id" />
    </div>
    <div className="padding5">
        <Field name="Password" type="Password" component={RenderField} label="Password" />
    </div>

    <div className='buttonSection'>
        <button type="submit" disabled={this.state.errors} className='buttonField padding5'>Reset Password</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Any feedback on our answers ?

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks fine. 
You have to use `Form` from `redux-form`:

```
import { reduxForm, Form } from 'redux-form';

// Your form component
<Form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
  // Your form
</Form>
```

Make sure you have add `redux-form` to your redux store:

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import { reducer as formReducer } from 'redux-form';

const combinedReducers = combineReducers({
  form: formReducer
})
```

and you are exporting your form wrapped:

```
import { reduxForm, Form } from 'redux-form';

// Your form

export default reduxForm({
  form: 'name-of-form'
})(MyForm);
```

Answer (score 0):

First you should use `Form` component from `redux-form`

```
import { reduxForm, Form, Field } from 'redux-form';
```

Also when connected to `redux-form` your component receives a `handleSubmit` prop you should use in your `onSubmit` event listener so it should be :

```
<Form onSubmit={this.props.handleSubmit(this.onSubmit)} />
```

Then your submit button will do the job calling `this.onSubmit` with a collection of values with field names as keys :

```
onSubmit = values => {
  console.log(values); // => { email: '', password: '' }
}
```